# Lifetime and usefulness of an object that is created inside an if statement in a method

Tags: c++, object, destructor, lifetime

This ic the class I want to use to understand destructors.

```
#include iostream
using namespace std;

class Student{
public:
Student(int num = 0)
{
id = num;
}
}
```

This is the method

```
void bar(int a)
{

if( a == 5)
Student S(5);

cout<<"after if"<<endl;

}
```

The thing is that if a = 5; object S of Student class is created and the object's life time ends with the if loop. The destructor called before the line after if. So  shouldn't it mean that creating objects inside loops is just a waste of time because we can't use them anymore? Or can they somehow be useful?

Comment: You can use them inside the loop, which is very useful.

Comment: If you have a loop, not just an `if` statement, this is a great way to make sure a variable is reset to a known state at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: "_So shouldn't it mean that creating objects inside loops is just a waste of time because we can't use them anymore?_" 1) Your example doesn't even contain a loop. 2) In your example, yes, it is useless. There are cases, however, where creating an object, with a lifetime limited to a particular scope would be useful (not mentioning the cases, where some object has purpose, only while being in some inner scope, one of the examples that comes to mind is: [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock)).

Comment: If you have ever written any algorithm, you have most likely used primitives that lived only inside a loop. Were they useless? Is anything on the stack useless since it dies when the main ends (or before)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you ask about *usefulness*.

If you only need an object to exist for a very short time but you still might want to hold on to that data, you can use **std::shared_ptr** to use smart pointers to dynamically allocate memory for the objects on the heap. The objects are very quick to access and is an easy way to make trivial use of them. You could do this with raw pointers but smart pointers are just safer, in that you won't ever get memory leaks from forgetting to delete a raw pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<Student> stu_ptr;

if (a == 5) 
    stu_ptr = (new (Student(a)));

stu_ptr->someClassFunction();
```

stu_ptr still exists after the if statement. If you wanted to do multiple checks/conditions you could keep reassigning that stu_ptr or, due to the nature of shared pointers, you could make new shared pointers to the same Student object to fulfill other trivial calculations/functionalities.